# Listing calendar events using Cordova calendar plugin on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, calendar, ionic-framework

I've implemented the ngCordova $cordovaCalendar plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/calendar/1 inside an ionic application (not important) and I'm making use of the `.listEventsInRange()` method which functions as expected on Android. I realise that this method doesn't work on iOS and the only available method is `.findEvent()`. However I need the same functionality on both platforms for a suggestive style search.

I've tried the `findAllEventsInNamedCalendar()` method but this only returns events that happen in the future and I'm after events within a range past, present and/or future.

My question is how do you find a list of events from an iOS device given a date range? It seems a little silly to lookup an event "exactly" if you don't know what you're looking for...seems a little stab around in the dark-ish.

I guess the question is two-fold: Does anyone have a working example of cordova calendar plugin listing events using iOS? Does anyone have an example of how to use `findEvent()`

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I found that the official docs didnt work for me on my ios device (iphone 6)

I eventually went here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/calendar/
note that the docs dont tell you that  find event takes an object NOT a list of params.

I created 2 apts on the calendar. one 9-10am and on 5-6 pm. I then used the code below to find apts between 2 dates (play with values of d and d1)

```
var d = new Date(2015, 5, 10, 9,30,0,0,0);
var d1 = new Date(2015, 5, 10, 10,30,0,0,0);
$cordovaCalendar.findEvent({
    title: '',
    location: '',
    notes: '',
    startDate: d,
    endDate: d1
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log('results', JSON.stringify(result, null, '\t'));
    console.log(new Date());
    console.log(d, d1);
}, function (err) {
    console.error('err', err);
});
```

Hope it helps